# How to arrange objects in outward facing circle?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, particles

I'm trying to mimic the look of soundproofing but on a cylindrical object - this pattern:

[image: reference image of soundproofing]

All the pyramids need to face outwards. I followed some tutorials on arranging things in a circle but the direction isn't correct and depending on scale they overlap:

[image: pyramid object arranged in a circle]

How can I make this pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can model this shape quite easily with just two modifiers.

First add a Cone, set the *Vertices* to 4 so that it is a pyramid, and lower the *Depth* to 1.
[image: Add Cone options]

Set the origin at the bottom of the pyramid. Now Rotate the pyramid so that it is pointing towards the negative Y axis.

[image: Cone in correct orientation]

Add an [Array Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html), and a [Simple Deform Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/simple_deform.html). For the simple deform modifier set the *Type* to **Bend**, the *Angle* to **360**, and the *Axis* to **Z**.

[image: modifiers]

Use the *Count* in the Array modifier to change the diameter of the cylinder.
[image: animated gif of the array count]

Last add another array modifier to the ring of pyramids, to get more then one row.

[image: Finished cylinder of pyramids]

Comment: Damn, that's an elegant solution. Bravo.

Answer (score 4):

**Add 1 row Cylinder Poke Faces.**

Another method to use would be add a cylinder with depth such that the faces are squares.. *could do the math* easy to alter later.

[image]

Select all the square faces and <kbd>F3</kbd> Poke faces.

Select all the "poke" vertices and scale desired amount.  (with median point as pivot)

Can now array the cylinder relative in z.

Notes:

This has been put forward as an alternative to positioning the single pyramid.

In as much as there are many ways to do this with duplis, particle systems or array modifiers using one pyramid. There will need to be some tweaking to avoid overlap or other issues.

A script would be one way to position them (using any method)  to calculate the radius given the number.